# What is solution for this error "ValueError: If evaluating from data tensors, you should specify the `steps` argument"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am testing my Deep learning model,  I wrote this code

```
from keras.models import load_model

classifier = load_model('Trained_model.h5')
classifier.evaluate()
```

## Prediction of single image

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
img_name = input('Enter Image Name: ')
image_path = './predicting_data/test_set/{}'.format(img_name)
print('')
```

after running, I am  getting this error

```
ValueError: If evaluating from data tensors, you should specify the `steps` argument.
```

NOTE :- ./predicting_data/test_Set  is the path of my test dataset which has sub folders like A b...c ...to z containing images

Comment: The code you included does not make any prediction, looks incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

The working code to Predict the Class of an Image, by Loading the Saved Model is shown below:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

Test_Dir = '/Dogs_Vs_Cats_Small/test/cats'

New_Model = tf.keras.models.load_model('Dogs_Vs_Cats.h5')
New_Model.summary()

Image_Path = os.path.join(Test_Dir, 'cat.1500.jpg')
Img = image.load_img(Image_Path, target_size = (150,150))
Img_Array = image.img_to_array(Img)
Img_Array = Img_Array/255.0
Img_Array = tf.reshape(Img_Array, (-1,150,150,3))

Predictions = New_Model.predict(Img_Array)

Label = tf.argmax(Predictions)

Label.numpy()[0]
```

Final line gives the respective Class for our Image.