# How fix "ValueError: When using data tensors as input to a model, you should specify the `steps` argument."?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to `predict()` the output for a single data, but I don't understand what means "ValueError If predicting from data tensors, you should specify the 'step' argument."?

Here is my code:

```
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('Xmodel_86.h5')
N='C:/Users/fatim/Desktop/MARIAM.Ser1.Img1 copy 2.jpg'

img = tf.keras.utils.load_img(
        N, target_size=(299, 299)
)
img_array = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
img_array = tf.reshape(img_array, (-1,299,299,3))# Create a batch
class_names = ['Benign', 'Malignant', 'Normal']
predictions = new_model.predict(img_array)
score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
print( "This image most likely belongs to {} with a {:.2f} percent confidence."
                    .format(class_names[np.argmax(score)], 100 * np.max(score)) )
```

Comment: Models are callable so you can just do `predictions = new_model(img_array)`. If you insist on using `predict`, you must tell the method after how many batches to stop the prediction (via `batch_size` and`step` arguments) [as per TF docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict).

Comment: Do these references help you to solve this issue? [ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63781754/valueerror-when-using-data-tensors-as-input-to-a-model) , [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60736676/14290681).

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the above mentioned code to predict the single image from the loaded model. It works fine.

```
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/model')
N='/content/images (1).jpeg'

img = tf.keras.utils.load_img(N, target_size=(28, 28))
img_array = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 2)
img_array = tf.reshape(img_array, (-1,28,28,1))predictions = new_model.predict(img_array)

score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
print( "This image most likely belongs to {} with a {:.2f} percent confidence."
                    .format(class_names[np.argmax(score)], 100 * np.max(score)) )
```

Output of the above code is:

```
This image most likely belongs to Bag with a 23.20 percent confidence.
```

Here i have just changed the shape of the image that matches to the model input.

For more details, please refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kiransair/ef793be1ac22483a8c8bb37295865d76). Thank You!